# Play! Framework synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I suggest adding [Play!] and [play-framework] as synonyms of the current [playframework](/questions/tagged/playframework) tag on Stack Overflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[play-framework](/questions/tagged/play-framework) is [already suggested as a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/playframework/synonyms) of [playframework](/questions/tagged/playframework), but it seems it needs more votes. I added one now. The text "Play!" is an invalid tag, so we don't have to worry about that one showing up.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I didn't know how to look up synonyms for a particular tag.  I thought maybe [TAG:play-framework] wasn't yet added because no questions show up under it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/play-framework?sort=newest&pagesize=15.  Maybe a bug?

Comment: Whoops, I was mistaken. It's not a synonym yet, just proposed as one. I corrected the answer, and voted to make it a synonym.

Comment: Ah, OK, got it.  Should I delete this question then?  Thanks!